# Elastic Search query return terms within array of a specific type

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-query

I've a mapping of an index as following:

`{"tagged_index":{"mappings":{"tagged":{"properties":{"tags":{"properties":{"resources":{"properties":{"tagName":{"type":"string"},"type":{"type":"string"}}}}},"content":{"type":"string"}}}}}}`

Where **Resources** is an array which can have multiple tags. For example

`{"_id":"82906194","_source":{"tags":{"resources":[{"type":"Person","tagName":"Kim_Kardashian",},{"type":"Person","tagName":"Kanye_West",},{"type":"City","tagName":"New_York",},...},"content":"  Popular NEWS ..."}}
,
{"_id":"82906195","_source":{"tags":{"resources":[{"type":"City","tagName":"London",},{"type":"Country","tagName":"USA",},{"type":"Music","tagName":"Hello",},...},"content":"  Adele's Hello..."}},
...`

I do know how to extract important terms[tagName] with the below query, but I do not want terms[tagName] of all types.
How can I extract only the terms which are for example Cities only [type:City]? (I would like to get a list of tagName where the type is City i.e. London, New_York, Berlin,...)

`{"size":0,"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"*","analyze_wildcard":true}}}},"aggs":{"Cities":{"terms":{"field":"tags.resources.tagName","size":10,"order":{"_count":"desc"}}}}}`

Following is how the required output should look like:

`{"took":1200,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":5179261,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]},"aggregations":{"Cities":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":46737,"sum_other_doc_count":36037440,"buckets":[{"key":"London","doc_count":332820},{"key":"New_York","doc_count":211274},{"key":"Berlin","doc_count":156954},{"key":"Amsterdam","doc_count":132173},...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
{
"_source" : ["tags.resources.tagName"]
 "query": {
    "term": {
       "tags.resources.type": {
          "value": "City"
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Above query will fetch those resources which are of type city provided resources is of `object` type.

**After Edit**

**Problem** Group By `Tag name` which are Of `city` Type. That would not be achieved with the current mapping you have. You will have to change resources field to [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) type.

Mapping would look like.

```
 "mappings": {
     "resource": {
        "properties": {
           "tags": {
              "properties": {
                 "content": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "resources": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                       "tagName": {
                          "type": "string"
                       },
                       "type": {
                          "type": "string"
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Final query would be :

```
{
 "size": 0,
 "query": {
  "nested": {
     "path": "tags.resources",
     "query": {
        "match": {
           "tags.resources.type": "city"
         }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
  "resources Nested path": {
     "nested": {
        "path": "tags.resources"
     },
     "aggs": {
        "city type": {
           "filter": {
              "term": {
                 "tags.resources.type": "city"
              }
           },
           "aggs": {
              "group By tagName": {
                 "terms": {
                    "field": "tags.resources.tagName"
                 }
              }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Output would be:

```
"aggregations": {
  "resources Nested path": {
     "doc_count": 6,
     "city type": {
        "doc_count": 2,
        "group By tagName": {
           "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
           "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
           "buckets": [
              {
                 "key": "london",
                 "doc_count": 1
              },
              {
                 "key": "new_york",
                 "doc_count": 1
              }
           ]
         }
       }
     } 
   }
```

Comment: Your query is equivalent to `search?q=tags.resources.type:city` I don't want all the results containing the type. I just want a list of tagName for type:city only i.e. London, New York, Berlin and so.

Comment: No it doesn't work like that. List can only be obtained by including aggregation `"aggs":{"2":{"terms"...` in the query. Your query is not meant to return lists.

Comment: Can you just provide a sample output that you intend to get ? I guess it is kind of unclear from the question?

Comment: I've added a sample output to my question.

Comment: Ohh.. finally got the question.. have changed my answer. Can u have a look